# Specifies variable bindings

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I have a problem understanding simple SPARQL demo with GraphDB:

```
PREFIX rd: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX schem: <http://schema.org/ns#>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
        BIND(?mybind AS ?id)
        ?id rd:label ?label.
      { ?id a schem:TouristAttraction}
      }
ORDER BY ASC(?label)
```

Do check it with GraphDB REST RDF4J API `$<varname>`

```
http://server01.local:7200/repositories/01?query=QUERY...&mybind=urn:uuid:0053083d-a9dc-45d4-9702-700633df563b
```

and

```
http://server01.local:7200/repositories/01?query=QUERY...
```

I get the same result. The bind didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the docs state that the binding prefix is a `$` symbol, I'd think you should consider this in your request, i.e. instead of `&mybind=` do `&$mybind=` . I mean, `$<varname>` is not `<$varname>` so the dollar symbol matters. At least that how I understand the syntax. I might be wrong though, Jeen Broekstra is likely to give the correct answer here soon

Comment: Thanks for your support

Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Test URL with:
... & $ mybind = ..

... & mybind = ..

in QUERY:
BIND (? Mybind AS? Id) 
or
BIND ($ mybind AS? Id)

Comment: Does your query return what you need in UI? I mean `BIND (<urn:uuid:​424bdc8c> AS ?id)` etc.

Comment: yes with the BIND(<urn:uuid:0053083d-a9dc-45d4-9702-700633df563b> AS ?id) does it work

Comment: The suggested method from UninformedUser works. Try `http://server01.local:7200/repositories/01?query=QUERY...&$mybind=urn:uuid:0053083d-a9dc-45d4-9702-700633df563b`

Comment: Or your query should look like: `curl http://server01.local:7200/repositories/01 --data 'query=PREFIX rd: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX schem: <http://schema.org/ns#> SELECT * WHERE { BIND(?mybind AS ?id) ?id rd:label ?label. { ?id a schem:TouristAttraction} } ORDER BY ASC(?label) &$mybind=urn:uuid:0053083d-a9dc-45d4-9702-700633df563b'`

Comment: many many thanks for your support. I have the solution  - the problem was <>
http://server01.local:7200/repositories/01?query=PREFIX%20rd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20PREFIX%20schem%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fns%23%3E%20SELECT%20*%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND(%24mybind%20AS%20%3Fid)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fid%20rd%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fid%20a%20schem%3ATouristAttraction%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC(%3Flabel)&%24mybind=%3Curn%3Auuid%3A6a8d8542-020f-478b-9413-783007c71fcc%3E